# selenium Web Driver does not return Wikipedia table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape a table containing the results of all the presidential elections that have been held in the united states. To do this, I want to use selenium. I believe the table I am trying to scrape is executed by a client-site script (javescript) therefore I tried to watch out for the presence of a particular tag before I scrape the site.[Note: I have tried scraping the page directly with beautiful soup, but I keep getting a "None" response].

Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas
#using selenium and shromedriver to extract the javascript wikipage 

scrape_options=Options()
scrape_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='web scraping master/chromedriver', options=scrape_options)
page_info=driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election')


#waiting for the javascript to load


try:WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"wikitable 
sortablejquetablesorter")))
finally:page=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})
```

this code does not return the desired result, rather it just returns a

```
TimeoutExceptionerror
```

no matter the amount of time I give it.

Also Note: when I replace the line:

```
try:WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"wikitable 
sortablejquetablesorter")))
```

with:

```
try:WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"wikitable")))
```

it returns the table i need but with only half of the data present in the original table.

I think there is something wrong with my code, but I can not seem to wrap my head around what the problem is. Can someone help me? I have been stuck here for too long.

Comment: Same code with a little addition to see the output returned me the original table. Maybe you are doing something wrong while outputting the data?

Comment: @Hikt, can you please share the modified code with me?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SW04kdNW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find element by `class_name` accepts only class name. It doesn't support multiple class names Instead use `css selector`.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter")))
    page=driver.page_source
except:
    print("No element found")

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
table=soup.select_one('.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter')  #css selector for beautiful soup
df=pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

To load data into data frame you need to import below library

```
import pandas as pd
```

If its not installed in your system then try install using

```
pip install pandas
```